# Formatting Date Output Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The output from my hash is giving me the following date time:

```
16 May 11 13:12:14 +0000
```

How do I go about formatting this into something sensible?

Thanks

Comment: What is "my hash"? What do you expect sensible time to be? Is this a Rails project? Only Ruby?

Comment: The question's tagged ruby on rails?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you are wanting this output in a view... First, you can create some formats:

```
# /config/locales/en.yml:
en:
  date:
    formats:
      full: "%b %d, %Y"

  time:
    formats:
      full: "%B %d, %Y at %I:%M%p"
```

Then you can display a datetime in a view using the `l` method with specified format:

```
<%= l @something.updated_at, :format => :full %>
```

This would display something like the following:

```
May 16, 2011 at 01:12pm
```

[More on the i18n formats](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

[List of available directives](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/strftime/)

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. Will give it a shot. B